# Laravel Update or Insert value in null field

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble inserting value in null field.

this is the table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->boolean('role_name')->default(0);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

this is the UserController

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'mobile_no' => 'required|max:11',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
        $user->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('profile')->with('updated', 'Profile successfully updated');
    }
```

I don't get error and the $message always says : "Profile successfully updated" but it is not really updated.

Comment: you don't have barangay, city and province in your table but you do expect it from your request validation.

Comment: oh yah i forgot to remove it.

Comment: so yeah. how to insert value in null ?

Comment: also dd($request->all())  result add in question

Comment: i did use dd($request->all() and saw the result. but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared that field as fillable in your model?

```
    protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'username',.....
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: yes i do have a model and i inserted all of it in the User.php (Model)